# what does 卵からかえったばかりの魚 mean?

Tags: meaning, formal-nouns

This sentence was from a JLPT N2 prep book.
卵からかえったばかりの魚は体が透き通っている。

I don't understand the part that modifies 魚. 
Here is how I parsed it:

卵から かえった ばかり の 魚
From egg/returned/just/noun modifier/fish

So I thought this means "The fish that just returned from eggs", which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: istrasci's answer is correct, and this is something you can solve by yourself by just looking it up in a dictionary more carefully.

Comment: thanks. I should have scrolled down more to see the かえる that didn't mean "return" or "replace".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This かえった (かえる; 孵【かえ】る) means "hatch".  "The fish that just hatched from (the) eggs."